# TeamCity getting stuck at Initializing page

Tags: ubuntu, teamcity, ubuntu-14.04, build-agent

I'm using a Ubuntu 14.04 machine. I've downloaded TeamCity 8.1.5, unpacked the files and started it through sudo ./bin/runAll.sh start. But when I open the Teamcity page (localhost:8111) it gets stuck at "Initializing TeamCity server components" page...Does anyone know what should I do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Take a look at the `teamcity-server.log` file in the TeamCity `logs` directory. The last few lines should tell you why it is stuck.

Answer (score 5):

TeamCity does not always log errors in the teamcity-server.log... it depends on what the error is. When I ran into this error, it was because I was installing TeamCity on VirtualBox Ubuntu 14.04 server that only had 1024GB ram allocated and Java was eating that all up and crashing the TeamCity server process.

Look for crash logs in /busy/services/teamcity/bin.

Something like this: hs_err_pid995.log

That's where I found my answer. I upped the memory allocation to 2048GB on my VM and it worked like a charm

Comment: I had this same issue and increasing the memory did the trick. You can either edit /path/to/TeamCity/bin/teamcity-server.sh or set an environment variable.

Comment: This definitely did it. You need at least 2gb of ram... I was trying to run on a 1gb DigitalOcean droplet. the server instance can't handle it.

See this article https://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2011/09/improving-performance-and-scalability-of-your-teamcity-server/

Answer (score 0):

It is expected to "get stuck" for a few minutes at the first run when it creates the database (BTW it is  a good idea to check if TeamCity database was even created).
If it doesn't go any further, I agree with Jonathon in the comments, you need to find out the reason in teamcity-server.log under \logs\